# What exactly does this Sphinx error-message mean? ... "[...] syntax error, unexpected ')' near '\/)|(\ [...]"

Tags: regex, sphinx

When I try to query:

```
(P \/ \-v)|(P \/)|(P)|(\/)|(\/ \-v)|(\-v)
```

then  Sphinx gives me:

```
error -index keyword_broad: syntax error, unexpected ')' 
near '\/)|(\/ \-v)|(\-v)'
```

similar problem with this query:

```
("^P \/ \-v$")|("^P \/$")|("^P$")|("^\/$")|("^\/ \-v$")|("^\-v$")
```

it gives me:

```
error -index keyword_phrase: 
syntax error, unexpected '$', expecting TOK_KEYWORD or TOK_INT near 
'\/$")|("^\/ \-v$")|("^\-v$")'
```

Any ideas what the problem is? Cause to me those queries seem just fine.

Comment: Are you actually searching for regex strings, or are you trying to search by them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a longshot, but try not escaping the forward-slashes, it's unneeded.

Comment: Well, the cause of the error-message turned out to be in both cases the part with the single escaped slash. Though keeping the escaped slash in the other or-operands didn't cause any noticable troubles. I'd be interested in how you come to the conclusion that escaping slashes isn't required.